# Repeat a JavaScript code in URL bar of browser

Tags: javascript

I want the following code to run every 30 seconds on a specific website. How can i do that from my browser? I paste the following code in URL bar and press enter, it works buy only once.

```js
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbtnNextLessonTop','')
```

Comment: problem is the page is going to refresh. So you would need to handle it some other way. Do you actually need the clientside code to run?

Comment: yes i need it to run it through browser either chrome or firefox. can we do it through some extension like TemperMonkey?

Comment: Yes, use tamper monkey. This is not a good question for stackoverflow though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the code is going to post back and reload the page, you are going to have to inject an iframe on the page with the page loaded and execute it.

```
var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.src = window.location.href;
document.body.appendChild(ifr);

function triggerIt() {
  ifr.contentWindow.__doPostBack(
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbtnNextLessonTop', '');
  window.setTimeout(triggerIt, 30000);
}

triggerIt();
```

If the iframe redirects, you can recreate the iframe each time.